# Saving interpolated images in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, save, interpolation

How can I save each interpolated image in Inkscape as separate images with the entire background and maintaining position of interpolated object quickly? For example I created interpolated images of a ball to animate it as rolling. I have around 10 images of ball in total. How can I save each ball with its background and position as separate images to make a gif animation of ball rolling?

Comment: You may check [Inkscape animation project](https://github.com/ErikHK/inkscape_animation) which is under development. [Video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u2Bjc9EXemw).

Answer (score 1):

Group each ball with its background.

Mark all the groups, choose Shift-Ctrl-E for export, choose the selection tab and mark "Batch export of 10 selected objects" (my translation from german GUI) and export them. This should give you 10 images, generically named like g12345.png.